# Problemas homestead Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

olá, ao tentar dar o comando no terminal vagrant up dentro da minha pasta homestead aparece o seguinte erro:

```
/home/brendol/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:91:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/brendol/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Errno::ENOENT)
from /home/brendol/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:91:in `block in configure'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:317:in `provision'
from /home/brendol/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:89:in `configure'
from /home/brendol/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `vagrantfile'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:671:in `unload'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

o meu homestead.yaml está assim:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: screencast.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/screencast 

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: 'APP_ENV'
      value: 'local'
    - key: 'APP_DEBUG'
      value: 'true'

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: Pode informar o OS?

Comment: Estou usando ubuntu 15.4 @gmsantos

Comment: @BrendolLourençon use a versão mais estável do ubuntu (14.x) atualmente o 15.x ainda está em "fase de adaptação"

Comment: @RafaelAcioly eu estava com versões anteriores até ontem, e estava dando muito bug, então opinei por deixar essa mesmo, mesmo assim creio eu que o problema não esta no SO e sim na chave de acesso SSH.